# How to use socket to send and receive message from server?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, server

Hi guys so I have a task where I'm suppose to send a message to a server, and then get a reply back. I keep getting `failed 1recvfrom failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)` error and I'm new to this socket stuff. Hopefully someone can help me out. Here's my async task:

```
 private class SendDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        private String reply = "";
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("ip",portNumber);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                //printWriter.write("hello there");

                printWriter.println("hello there");
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                printWriter.flush();
                reply = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if(reply != null && !reply.equals(""))
                {
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"my message is " + reply);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"no message yet");
                }
                Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break 3");
                printWriter.close();

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"failed " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void var)
        {
            tv_response.setText(reply);
        }
    }
```

- Note: When I put the if statement to check for the null readline before `printWriter.flush()` I still get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printWriter.close();
```

Closing the input or output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket. Remove both occurrences.

```
if(bufferedReader.readLine() != null)
```

This doesn't make sense. You are throwing the line away and then reading the next line if it wasn't null. You need to store the result into a variable.

You probably need to use `printWriter.println()` instead of `printWriter.write()`. Probably the peer is reading lines too, and you aren't sending one (no line terminator).

If `reply == null` it means the peer has closed the connection. Not 'no message yet'. An empty string may be a protocol error but it also is not 'no message yet'.

Comment: I updated my code in the question. I stored the bufferedReader.readLine() in the `reply` variable. However, the LOG statement after I set reply variable doesn't run and I don't understand why, I'm hoping I wrote this correctly.

Comment: You probably need to use `printWriter.println()` instead of `printWriter.write()`. Probably the peer is reading lines too, and you aren't sending one.

Comment: printWriter doesn't have a println() method as im seeing on my android studio compiler. And I don't understand when you say "peer is reading lines too, and not sending one". Would you be able to clarify?

Comment: [Oh yes it does.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println-java.lang.String-) A line is terminated by a line terminator, and you aren't sending one, and you aren't (now) closing the socket, so a `readLine()` at the peer would block forever, which is exactly what is happening. And NB You need to flush it before reading.

Comment: oh it worked! Thanks for that. So would you be able to explain what flush does and why it needs to come before readLine()?

Comment: It flushes the `PrintWriter`, obviously. If you don't do it before the read, nothing has been sent, so why would the peer reply? so why would you read? and what good would flushing after the read do?

Comment: okay, (sorry very new to these terminologies). So .flush() is the actual action that sends my string or whatever data to the server end?

Comment: It flushes the `Writer`'s buffer if any. The buffer may be absent, or empty, in which case it does nothing, but if it isn't it does.

Comment: if I wanted to run an async task that continuously listened for any inputs from the server, would I just write a while loop in doInBackground that runs until bufferedReader.readLine() != null?

Comment: lets say from user 1 sends a message to server, and then the server wants to redirect that message to all the other user's devices. that's the use case im getting at