# android - how to run 2 sockets to the same IP and port?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, android-asynctask

so im making a very tiny messaging app. I have 1 async tasks that listens for messages from a server and another Async Task that sends messages to the server and echos back the message. For some reason I cannot send and listen to the server at the same time. this is the order of sequence of what happens:

1.User A enters a message and click send. Nothing happens.
2.User B, (has the listening async task off) and sends a message,
THEN userA's message comes back as well as user Bs. I don't know why I user A cannot send and listen for messages at the same time. Here are my 2 async tasks.

```
 private class CommunicateWithServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        private String jsonReply = "";
        private String jsonOutputToServer = "";

        public CommunicateWithServerAsyncTask(String jsonMessage)
        {
            this.jsonOutputToServer = jsonMessage;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break 1");
            try
            {
                Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break 2");
                Socket socket = new Socket("ip",portNumber);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                printWriter.println(jsonOutputToServer);
                printWriter.flush();
                jsonReply = bufferedReader.readLine();
                Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break 2");
                if(jsonReply != null && !jsonReply.equals(""))
                {
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break 3");
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"my message is " + jsonReply);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break 4");
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"no message yet");
                }
                printWriter.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                socket.close();

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"failed " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void var)
        {
            displayMessageFromServer(jsonReply,false);
        }
    }
```

Second Async Task

```
private class ListenForMessagesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    private String jsonReply = "";
    //private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break A");
        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket("52.91.109.76",1234);;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            while (isListeningForMessages)
            {
                Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break D");
                Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"my buffer reader value is " + String.valueOf(bufferedReader.ready()));
                if(bufferedReader.ready())
                {
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break E");
                    jsonReply = (String) bufferedReader.readLine();
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break F");
                    isListeningForMessages = false;//we have a reply, close the while loop and Async Task.
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"my listening message is " + jsonReply);
                }
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            socket.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"failed " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Void var)
    {
        displayMessageFromServer(jsonReply,true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I told you in my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47899231/207421) that `readLine(https://stackoverflow.com/q/47899231/207421)` returning null does not mean 'no message yet', and what it does mean.

Comment: So your async tasks are used in different client apps on two devices. Why didnt you you tell so?

Comment: Which messages are received by the different clients depends on what the server sends and to whom. You did not tell anything about your server. Nor did you post your server code. So how should we know what should happen?

Comment: Please do not talk about users but name them client app A and client app B.

Comment: @EJP oh jeez i should of re read that. So I don't check for null at all then, then whats the line of code that checks if something is coming in from server side, because currently, my second async task doesn't run at all.

Comment: @greenapps yeah I didn't write the server, but the server is suppose to return a json string. So if client app A write a "hello" and presses the send button, 2 things happen: First, it echos me back a json string with the message I sent it. Second, it sends all other devices the message "hello". Therefore, in order to test if I can write and listen to messages client app A wrote I used 2 Async tasks.

Comment: @EJP because when I was sending stuff to the server I had a PrintWriter object, but when I listen do I also need a PrintWriter object?

Comment: `2 things happen: First, it echos me back a json string with the message I sent it`. But you dont get a response you told. So solve that first before you mess around with another client.

Comment: @greenapps Yeah I'm able to get the first part done. So, without the listening async tasks it works. client app A can write "hello" and the server will send back a json string. However, its when i add the other async task its the bufferreader.readline() that blocks everything thats the problem

Comment: `bufferedReader.close();
                    socket.close();`. Those lines should be below the while loop. Otherwise your while makes no sense.

Comment: `Socket socket = new Socket("ip",portNumber);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); `Sorry... i do not see the logic of your code. Why creating a new socket after reading just one line? If you create a new socket then the close() commands were on the right place. 
    `

Comment: @greenapps yeah sorry, I was just trying to get stuff to work. But I updated the second async tasks, but it seems that the buffer reading in the listening async still blocks all other async tasks from running.

Comment: @greenapps I have something works below, let me know if I can do any major optimizations of if there's a more proper way to do it.

Comment: The 'line of code that checks if something is coming in' is `readLine()`. If nothing comes from the server, `readLine()` will *block*. You *must also* check for null, but it means peer disconnection, so you should close the socket. I don't understand why you're asking about `PrintWriters` for listening. It doesn't begin to make sense.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted a very simple way for user 1 to send a message to the server. The server echos a response as well as send that message to user 2.

To accomplish sending messages to the server and getting an echo response you can look at CommunicateWithServerAsyncTask. Here, we connect to the server with a socket object and we're able to send messages to the server using the Typewriter class. Next, we use the buffer reader class to listen for any message response from the server.

In order for user 2 to receive user 1's messages from the server, we have to continuously listen for a response from the server and that's why I implemented the CommunicateWithServerAsyncTask. Same concept as the first AsyncTask, but we just need the socket and bufferreader objects in a while loop.

Hope this helps someone who's trying to figure out the basics of socket connections. In this answer, I already assume you have a serving running somewhere and need help on the client side.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button b_send;
    private EditText et_message;
    private TextView tv_response, userB_TV;
    private boolean isSendButtonPressed;
    private final String SOCKET_TESTING_TAG = "SOCKET_TESTING_TAG";
    private static boolean isListeningForMessages = true;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private ListenForMessagesAsyncTask listenForMessagesAsyncTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bindActivity();

    }
    private void bindActivity()
    {
        b_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_send);
        et_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);
        tv_response = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_response);
        userB_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_history);
        tv_response.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        b_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if(!et_message.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !isSendButtonPressed)//I do a couple checks to make sure the user doesn't send an empty string and that they don't keep tapping the button
                {
                    isSendButtonPressed = true;
                    listenForMessagesAsyncTask.cancel(true);
                    try
                    {
                        socket.close();
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    CommunicateWithServerAsyncTask communicateWithServerAsyncTask = new CommunicateWithServerAsyncTask(convertMessageToJson(et_message.getText().toString()));
                    communicateWithServerAsyncTask.execute();//Note: you could do new CommunicateWithServerAsyncTask.execute(""); However, im just used to initiating async tasks this way.

                }
            }
        });
        listenForMessagesAsyncTask = new ListenForMessagesAsyncTask();
        listenForMessagesAsyncTask.execute();
    }

    private class CommunicateWithServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        private String jsonReply = "";
        private String jsonOutputToServer = "";

        public CommunicateWithServerAsyncTask(String jsonMessage)
        {
            this.jsonOutputToServer = jsonMessage;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket socket = new Socket("ip",portNumber);
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                printWriter.println(jsonOutputToServer);
                printWriter.flush();
                jsonReply = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if(jsonReply != null && !jsonReply.equals(""))
                {
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"my message is " + jsonReply);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"no message yet");
                }
                printWriter.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                socket.close();

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"failed " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void var)
        {
            displayMessageFromServer(jsonReply,false);
        }
    }

    private class ListenForMessagesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        private String jsonReply = "";
        //private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                socket = new Socket("ip",portNumber);;
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                while (isListeningForMessages)
                {
                    //Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break D");
                    if(bufferedReader.ready())
                    {
                        Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break E");
                        jsonReply = (String) bufferedReader.readLine();
                        Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"break F");
                        isListeningForMessages = false;//we have a reply, close the while loop and Async Task.
                        Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"my listening message is " + jsonReply);
                    }
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                socket.close();

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.d(SOCKET_TESTING_TAG,"failed " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void var)
        {
            displayMessageFromServer(jsonReply,true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This isn't much use to anybody unless you state what's different and why that's better.

Comment: @EJP okay let me add a lot of details